# NSJSONSerialization Returns Error of NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have the following code :

```
NSData * jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [newStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *jsonError;

    if (jsonError) {
       NSLog(@"JSON Error %@", [jsonError localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSArray * jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
```

Which is parsing the following JSON String :

```
{"author":"Oli Riman","content":"The museum shows us a view of pre-WWI society that includes doubts, fears, political protests etc. through newspaper cartoons of the time. Really interesting for adults who enjoy history. I wouldn't suggest this for kids who haven't studied WWI history or who don't read easily.","rating":"5","placeId":"40","date":"29-June-2015","reviewId":"9905A52D-76B2-4D42-8CA8-9158225C0D07"}
```

However I am getting a strange error code of :

domain: (null) - code: 0

Can anyone advise on what is causing this ?

Comment: Top level is a `NSDictionary`, not a `NSArray`? Plus, why NSData => NSString => NSData ?

Comment: Sorry, JSON is actually an array - simplified it for purposes of the question.

Comment: I just run your code and its running fine, with a remote json structure: `[{"id":"1","name":"karlo"},{"id":"1","name":"karlo"}....etc]`

Comment: Which means you have to check your json stucture, your connection and all basic debug.

Comment: Sorry added in the line that's actually crashing - it's the NSLog after if (jsonError)

Comment: Thats your json structure -> https://karlol.com/TEST/so.json? Im still not getting the error.

Comment: Yep exactly that Karlo. Really odd.

Comment: I would like to see the conclusion of this cause I cant figure out thats going on and I work a lot with json parse.

Comment: Turned out there's nothing wrong with the JSON bit after all, it was because the project's class had arc turned off and the NSError wasn't instantiated properly :/ Will try and close.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested the code on my simulator. Its working. You need to check if you are getting data from server or not.
If you want to test the parsing thing, you can do one thing-
Just store the data in json file and save it in the app bundle lets say file is "data.json"
and call below method, you will get data for sure.

```
- (void)readJsonData {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data
                                                         options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                           error: &error];
    NSLog(@"Parsed json data- %@", dict);

}
```

Comment: Same problem. Agree the swapping to string and back is redundant, however it shouldn't make any differences to the integrity of the data.